# Laravel-Vue > importing public assets or resources?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use Laravel with Vuejs, and I would like to know which assets I need to import on my components.

Usually with only Laravel, I import the ones coming from the public folder (webpack before).

But here with VueJS I have to import those from the resources folder (not yet switched to webpack), or the same as for Laravel, I take those from the public folder?

PS: When I npm run watch, it's running me in a loop, with the assets coming from the public folder.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should import Public assets.

in View:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{mix('css/app.css')}}">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <vue>
        </vue>
    </div>

    <script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since you're using `VueJS` i'll recommend to use `mix()` instead of `assets()` since `mix` will help you to don't clear cache to get new update on your site while it's online.